# How to mapping the price of an asset with chain links and solidity?

Tags: oracle, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I have a contract that has to save the time and price of eth via chainlink. The time works and has no problems. The price, on the other hand, fails to be recorded either with an array or with a mapping. I have tried several solutions, which include `push()`.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

interface EACAggregatorProxy {
    function latestAnswer() external view returns (int256);
}

contract oracleLink {

    uint256 deadline;
 
    uint256 startTime = startTimes[block.timestamp]; 
    mapping(uint => uint) startTimes; 

    address public chainLinkETHUSDAddress = 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331;

    uint public ethPrice = 0; 
    uint256 price = ethPrice;
    mapping(uint => uint) ethPrice;

    function priceOnTime() public payable {

        deadline = block.timestamp + (numberOfSeconds * 1 seconds);

        int256 chainLinkEthPrice = EACAggregatorProxy(chainLinkETHUSDAddress).latestAnswer();
        ethPrice = uint(chainLinkEthPrice / 100000000);
        return ethPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: On which network are you deploying the contract? (e.g. Ethereum mainnet, Ropsten testnet, Remix VM London, ...)

Comment: Hi @Petr on testnet Kovan, testnet Rinkeby and VM London.

Answer (score 0):

The [chainLinkETHUSDAddress](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331#code) address hardcoded in your source contains a contract only on the Kovan testnet. Meaning, this code works only on this testnet or its forks, and fails on other networks.

If you want to use the returned value in Remix, you need to create a local fork of the Kovan testnet and then connect to this local network using the Environment selectbox in Remix.

Comment: Yes, in the code I posted there is Kovan's address. My problem is not that. The problem though is that I can't map 'price' and I still don't understand why. The code without mapping works fine but if I want to map prices for each price request this is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not using the mapping correctly. I mapping is like an array, just more efficient in some ways, but also has some limitations.

so to use your mapping you need to use it as

ethPrice[x] = y;

Where both x and y are an uint (as you specified the mapping uint => uint). So each unique uint maps (refers) to another uint.

ethPrice[x] = uint(chainLinkEthPrice / 100000000);

Where x is an uint you use to lookup the value later on with.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I get an error from the console, I tried following your advice but it keeps generating an error. 

I created a variable " uint256 ethPrice[x] = price;"
I mapped "mapping(uint => uint) ethPrice;"

And in the body of the function I used: 

"ethPrice[x] = uint(chainLinkEthPrice / 1000000);"

Unfortunately, it keeps returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrectly storing the mapping. Mapping has to be stored as `variable[key]=value`.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_mappings.htm